# How to get first letter of each word from a text box?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using an MS Access database.

I have a single textbox called [CUSTOMER NAME] which has a data like:

- JONES CLARENCE J
- MORRIS D
- MORRIS ART & ANNE

I want to get the initials of those names to a different textbox as follows:

- J.C.J.
- M.D.
- M.A.A.

Answer (score 4):

You can leverage the VBA [`Split`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-function-876f246a-5144-44fa-889f-10078c7878f5) function for this task: supplied with a string and delimiter, this function will split the string at each occurrence of the delimiter and return an array of substrings.

In your case, the delimiter is a space, e.g.:

```vb
?Split("JONES CLARENCE J", " ")(0)
JONES
?Split("JONES CLARENCE J", " ")(1)
CLARENCE
?Split("JONES CLARENCE J", " ")(2)
J
```

From there, you can use the [`Left`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/left-function-d5897bf6-91f5-4bf8-853a-b63d7de09681) function to return the first character of each substring:

```vb
?Left(Split("JONES CLARENCE J", " ")(0),1)
J
?Left(Split("JONES CLARENCE J", " ")(1),1)
C
?Left(Split("JONES CLARENCE J", " ")(2),1)
J
```

With this knowledge we can construct a simple function to iterate over the array of substrings and obtain the 1st character of each substring, e.g.:

```vb
Function InitialiseString(strNme As String) As String
    Dim strSub As Variant
    For Each strSub In Split(strNme, " ")
        Debug.Print Left(strSub, 1)
    Next strSub
End Function
```

```vb
?InitialiseString("JONES CLARENCE J")
J
C
J
```

Though, we will want to exclude strings such as the ampersand in your example:

```vb
?InitialiseString("MORRIS ART & ANNE")
M
A
&
A
```

Which we can do with the inclusion of a simple `if` statement to test the character before outputting it:

```vb
Function InitialiseString(strNme As String) As String
    Dim strSub As Variant
    For Each strSub In Split(strNme, " ")
        If Left(strSub, 1) Like "[A-Za-z]" Then
            Debug.Print Left(strSub, 1)
        End If
    Next strSub
End Function
```

```vb
?InitialiseString("MORRIS ART & ANNE")
M
A
A
```

Finally, given a valid character, we need to construct the output:

```vb
Function InitialiseString(strNme As String) As String
    Dim strSub As Variant
    For Each strSub In Split(strNme, " ")
        If Left(strSub, 1) Like "[A-Za-z]" Then
            InitialiseString = InitialiseString & Left(strSub, 1) & "."
        End If
    Next strSub
End Function
```

```vb
?InitialiseString("JONES CLARENCE J")
J.C.J.
?InitialiseString("MORRIS D")
M.D.
?InitialiseString("MORRIS ART & ANNE")
M.A.A.
```

Comment: @karthikAlagirisamy You're most welcome! If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate) so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks!